# Assumption of linear regression

Tags: linear-regression

I am confused with the independence assumption of Linear Regression

Should the features be independent or observations be independent ?

If observation be independent is the answer I struggle with interpreting that, does that mean observation 1 should have no effect on determining observation 10's target variable value?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156095/linear-regression-assumption . If still has further questions, you may post in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a math question having nothing to do with software development. Another comment refers OP to a related question on math.stackexchange.com